# Optional functions in a discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a command that creates an embed based on a message in discord such as:

!embed #FF0000 - Hello - World - https:/random_image.png

but how can I make a parameter optional, for example make an embed without image

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "embed",
    description: "Genera un embed en base a un imput",
    permissions: ["BAN_MEMBERS"],
    
    async execute(client, message, args, discord) {

        if (! message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("No tienes permiso para usar este comando.")

        const msgcontent = args.join(" ");
        const msgsplit = msgcontent.split(' - ');
        const color = msgsplit[0]
        const title = msgsplit[1]
        const description = msgsplit[2]
        const image = msgsplit[3]

        if(!color) return message.channel.send('¡Ingresa el codigo HEX que quieres en tu embed!');
        if(!title) return message.channel.send("¡Ingresa el título que quieres en tu embed!");
        if(!description) return message.channel.send("Ingresa la descripción que quieres en tu embed!");
        if (!image) return message.channel.send("Ingresa el link de la imagen que quieres en tu embed!")

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(`${color}`)
        .setTitle(`${title}`)
        .setDescription(`${description}`)
        .setImage(`${image}`)

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image field is empty, you can create a new embed without it. Kind of like this

```
    if(image === undefined){

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(`${color}`)
        .setTitle(`${title}`)
        .setDescription(`${description}`)

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

}
```

Or state the embed before and then use the return function.

```
   if(image === undefined) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```